# Error parsing JSON: undefined method 'gsub'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I'm trying to parse JSON in JavaScript, but I'm getting this error in Rails:

```
undefined method `gsub' for #<Array:0x000001054a2440>
```

my code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var stuff = <%= escape_javascript(@json) %>
  var json = stuff.parseJSON();
  alert("text");
</script>
```

where @json is defined in the controller as @nodes.to_json

Can someone please help me with this? Getting JSON to JavaScript shouldn't be hard, but it's taking me forever.

Comment: Perhaps it'd be helpful if you noted which version of Rails you're using. Also, what do you want to do with the JSON? Is it necessary for it to be output to an HTML page? Or do you want to respond to a request with JSON directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code for [`escape_javascript`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/JavaScriptHelper.html#method-i-escape_javascript) is:

```
def escape_javascript(javascript)
  if javascript
    javascript.gsub(/(\\|<\/|\r\n|[\n\r"'])/) { JS_ESCAPE_MAP[$1] }
  else
    ''
  end
end
```

Thus, I would conclude that `@json` is actually an Array.

Answer (score 1):

you are applying gsub methods for array that's why undefined method `gsub' for # occur. @json is array and you cant apply gsub on it.

Comment: Thanks everyone. The reason I'm getting that error is because of escape_javascript. I only added that because I thought I needed it in order to parse the JSON. If thats not the case, how can I simply parse the JSON in javascript? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use JSON.parse if natively available or else include a json parser, the most popular one is written by Douglas Crockford